# Why doesn't XOpenDisplay() fail with bad display names

Tags: c, unix, x11

Can anybody explain to me why XOpenDisplay() doesn't fail with bad display names? As long as the names follow the syntax convention, it always seems to succeed - even if the specified host name doesn't exist. XOpenDisplay() only seems to fail if the string uses a bad syntax, e.g.

```
d = XOpenDisplay("foobar");       // fails - presumably because of bad syntax in string
d = XOpenDisplay("foobar:0.0");   // works - although there is no host named "foobar"
```

When specifying a hostname that doesn't exist, XOpenDisplay() seems to fallback to $DISPLAY. Is that how it is supposed to be? I didn't find anything about these fallbacks in the Xlib documentation. If it is correct behaviour, is there a way to check whether the returned display really connected me to "foobar:0.0" or whether it is just a fallback to $DISPLAY?

Comment: `// works`. Not for me.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't seem to happen on all Linuxes. My ancient installation of openSUSE always fails with bad display names, i.e. it behaves as one would expect it. However, my installations of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Linux Mint Maya both show the behaviour that I presented above.

Comment: You may have a catch-all DNS somewhere.

Comment: So how can I check if that is the case? If it is the case, I certainly haven't done this deliberately but the fact that the wrong behaviour shows up on two entirely different versions of Linux rather speaks against a misconfiguration. But I can check that if you tell me where to look. I've already checked out /etc/hosts but the only thing I modified there is to assign NetBIOS names to the fixed IP addresses of the different machines in my network. Nothing else.

Comment: Try something like 'host foobar' or 'ping foobar' from the shell.

Comment: You can also try to capture network traffic and do `strace` on your program in order to figure out what's going on. All in all this behaviour is very strange and disturbing. If I want to connect to host foobar and for some reason the network is not available, I definitely do not want X to pretend everything is OK.

Comment: ping: unknown host foobar .. Host foobar not found: 3(NXDOMAIN) ... tomorrow I'll try one of the latest live DVDs and see if it's still there

Answer (score 0):

That does seem like rather weak behavior, but http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html says:

> The encoding and interpretation of the display name is implementation
>   dependent.

So it seems that this "interpretation" is allowed.

To tell if the default display was opened instead, you might try:

```
d_default = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
d = XOpenDisplay("foobar:0.0");
if (!d || d == d_default) {
  // foobar:0.0 was not opened.
}
```

If this doesn't work because `d` and `d_default` are different even though referring to the same hardware, you might try comparing a field of the `_XDisplay` struct instead of the returned pointers, which are apparently pointing to different structs which somewhere must have similar data since they reference the same hardware. See the following reference for possibilities, but the simplest (if it works) might be to see if `d->fd == d_default->fd`.

Reference: http://xwindow.angelfire.com/page28.html

Comment: I tried that but funnily, XOpenDisplay(NULL) returns a different pointer than XOpenDisplay("foobar:0.0") although they obviously connect to the same X server.

Comment: Hmm, but that still doesn't solve the problem that "foobar:0.0" might actually be the name of the default X server... checking "foobar:0.0" against $DISPLAY is also not a good solution because $DISPLAY mostly contain just something like ":0". So one would somehow have to obtain the name of the default X server and then also compare it against this. I'm not sure but is it even possible to assign several hostnames to the current machine in /etc/hosts? Then we'd have even more problems to find out whether the given server name is valid or junk...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to force connection to a particular display is to stick the desired display name into the environment:

```
setenv("DISPLAY", "foobar:0.0", 1);
d = XOpenDisplay(0);
```

This is generally also desirable as the proper display name is also propagated to any child processes that are started, though if you want to avoid that, you could record the old `$DISPLAY` and restore it afterwards.

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't make a difference. XOpenDisplay() still succeeds if $DISPLAY has been set to some fantasy hostname that doesn't exist.